# Does Entity Framework 6.1 support an XML data type natively?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Some RDBMSs (including SQL Server) support XML columns. I'd prefer not mapping such a column to the `string` data type. Does Entity Framework 6.1 support XML natively in any way?

More specifically, can I map an `xml` column to one of the XML data types of .NET (such as `XElement` or `XmlElement`)? Does Entity Framework support XQuery that is integrated into normal LINQ queries and is translated to SQL queries?

Comment: [The answer is no.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2e6aa49-f573-4dca-a1e7-505841c3c668/entity-framework-treats-xml-type-in-sql-server-as-a-string?forum=adodotnetentityframework)

Comment: Natively, no, but the link @Aron provided shows a way to at least expose the result as an XElement.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, only mapping it to string and then having to stream it back in to an XML document.

There is a long thread back and forth with Microsoft about doing this in EF4, 5, or 6, but it looks like they researched it and decided to punt.

You can read that here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fb290076-f97d-41f4-9801-505ccf5ef1d6/entity-framework-and-sql-xml-data-type?forum=adodotnetentityframework