# How can I construct a data model to bind to a SQL table with an XML column

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use ASP.NET Core to read from a SQL database. I'm using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext and I have it working except for any tables that have an XML column

When try and read from one of these tables I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The entity type 'SqlXml' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.
```

I know this isn't talking about my model as it does have a primary key. It seems to be talking about the SqlXml class.

How can I construct a data model to bind to a SQL table with an XML column?

The DBContext

```
    public class HistoryContext : DbContext
    {
        public HistoryContext(DbContextOptions<HistoryContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<ShWorkflowRunsModel> shWorkflowRuns { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ShWorkflowRunsModel>().ToTable("sh_workflowRuns");
        }
    }
```

The Model

```
    public class ShWorkflowRunsModel
    {
        [Key]
        public Int64 runId { get; set; }
        public Guid serviceId { get; set; }
        public string serviceName { get; set; }
        public Guid workflowId { get; set; }
        public SqlXml workflowConfig { get; set; }
        public DateTime startTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime endTime { get; set; }
        public bool isScheduled { get; set; }
        public string errorMessage { get; set; }
        public bool hasErrorCounters { get; set; }
    }
```

The Controller

```
    public class WorkflowController : Controller
    {
        private HistoryContext _context;

        public WorkflowController(HistoryContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult History(string workflowId)
        {
            List<ShWorkflowRunsModel> model = GetShWorkflowRuns(workflowId);
            return View(model);
        }

        public List<ShWorkflowRunsModel> GetShWorkflowRuns(string workflowId)
        {
            return _context.shWorkflowRuns.Where(wr => wr.workflowId.ToString() == workflowId).ToList();
        }

    }
}
```

The SQL table definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sh_workflowRuns](
    [runId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [serviceId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [serviceName] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
    [workflowId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [workflowConfig] [xml] NOT NULL,
    [startTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [endTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [isScheduled] [bit] NULL,
    [errorMessage] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
    [hasErrorCounters] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_sh_workflowRuns] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [runId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Please let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 3):

You get this error message because EF Core thinks that `SqlXml` is one of your entities and tries to map it to a DB table, and obviously it can't find any Id on the `SqlXml` class.

I don't think that that current version of EF Core has native support XML. You have to read and write it as string, and you can create a wrapper like they do it in these examples:

[XML columns in a Code-First application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631290/xml-columns-in-a-code-first-application)

[Does Entity Framework 6.1 support an XML data type natively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219515/does-entity-framework-6-1-support-an-xml-data-type-natively)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2e6aa49-f573-4dca-a1e7-505841c3c668/entity-framework-treats-xml-type-in-sql-server-as-a-string?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: EF core has [value conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) for this purpose.

Comment: @hujtomi Apologies, I might need more guidance. If I just set the type to string within the model, I still get exactly the same error (The entity type 'SqlXml' requires a primary key to be defined.). How can I construct a wrapper if I can't even read the value in as a string?

Comment: you changed `public SqlXml workflowConfig { get; set; }` to `public string workflowConfig { get; set; }` in your `ShWorkflowRunsModel` class and you still get the exception?

Comment: @hujtomi Exactly right, it even mentions SqlXml in the message which is surprising!

Comment: I think you should clean and build your project, I made a new sample project where I used your model class with `string workflowConfig` property and your controller and DBcontext, and I don't get the error. If it still does not work for you, then I think you should create a minimal sample project and share the code.